# std::map find distance with iterators, program does not terminate

Tags: c++, iterator, range, distance, stdmap

As I compile ( `g++ -std=c++14 map.cpp` ) and run this program, it doesn't seem to terminate. Can any one explain Why? However as I do find('a') instead of 'c' it gives a zero.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map> 
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std; 



int main()
{
    map<char, float> m;
    m['a'] = 3.4;
    m['b'] = 5.3;
    m['c'] = 33.3;
    m['d'] = 43.;

    auto it = m.find( 'c' );
    cout << "distance : " << std::distance( it , m.begin() ) << endl;

}
```

Comment: About [using namespace std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
std::distance( m.begin(), it  )
```

Otherwise the call

```
std::distance( it , m.begin() )
```

has undefined behavior because there is used an invalid range. Ranges in C++ are specified like `[first, last )` where first precedes or equal to last. In the last case when first is equal to last the range is empty.

From the C++ Standard (27.4.3 Iterator operations)

> 4 Effects: If InputIterator meets the requirements of random access
>   iterator, returns (last - first); otherwise, **returns the number of
>   increments needed to get from first to last**.

Comment: Could you clarify *why* it's an invalid range?

Answer (score 3):

`std::distance(first,last)` starts running from `first` and advances the iterator until it reaches the `last`. In your case this will never happen because `it` is most likely found **after** `m.begin()` so it'll loop forever. change the order of parameters given to `std::distance`

**[std::distance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) reference:**

> The behavior is undefined if last is not reachable from first by
>   (possibly repeatedly) incrementing first.

Comment: Hm... Most likely (unless we crash instead), at some point the pointer value will overflow, and we restart from null pointer onwards again (all this undefined behaviour, of course), then finally reach at some point the begin() iterator again. So we indeed *would* stop at some point. Provided difference type is not larger than type of pointer, we'd even get negative value of desired distance due to overflow (well, UB again, if difference type is signed)... – Not criticism, just mentioning a funny issue ;)